How can I handle SingleLiveEvent from ViewModel to show Dialog in Composable Function?
I use this code to show snackBar or AlertDialog but it can only show only first time
LaunchedEffect(mySingleLiveEvent.value) {
        if (mySingleLiveEvent.value?.error?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
            snackBarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = "msg",
                actionLabel = "label",
                duration = SnackbarDuration.Short,
            )
        }
    }


Does this answer your question? VIewModel observeAsState as Single event in Android Compose
